# nodejs: setInterval for custom function

Tags: node.js, setinterval, intervals

I have the following function:

```
getHostlist() {
        fs.readFile('out/hostlist', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        var hostlist = data.split(',');
        this.getHostStats(hostlist);
    });
},
```

it is exported.

in my index.js im trying to call it with setInterval every minute:
`setInterval(remote.getHostlist, config.app.refresh);` the second parameters contains 60000.

So i try to run it every minute.

But when it runs im recieving the following error:
`TypeError: this.getHostStats is not a function`

But when i run the function manually without interval it works and `getHostStats` is called.

Where is the problem here`?

EDIT FULL EXPORT SCRIPT:

```
module.exports = {
getHostlist() {
    console.log("Starting Usage synchronization at " + currTime());
    fs.readFile('out/hostlist', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        var hostlist = data.split(',');
        getHostStats(hostlist);
    });
},
....
}
```

if i write everything down here it would be to long.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this scenario "this" is referring to wherever your setInterval code is running so "this" is no longer remote. Try and get an explicit reference to `remote.getHoststats`and use that instead.

//EDIT 1//
It may be worth wrapping your export functions into a class, creating an object of that class and then exporting the object. That should guarantee that "this" works in your context

Comment: Can you explain to me how this should work? I cant replace this.getHoststats with remote.getHostStats, because the name remote is unique to my index.js

Comment: Please provide the full export script.

Comment: Edited for youu

Comment: Could you write me an example, im not sure how to realize this. I tried with `class remote {...}` and at the end `module.exports.remote;` but im still getting the same error message. i only know `export default class remote` which i use for react-native, but my nodejs app is not running es6 and i think this is a es6 feature right?

Comment: so class remote {functions bla} const object = new remote(); module.exports = remote;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
module.exports = {
getHostlist : function getHostlist() {
    console.log("Starting Usage synchronization at " + currTime());
        fs.readFile('out/hostlist', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
          if (err) throw err;

         var hostlist = data.split(',');
         getHostStats(hostlist);
     });
  }
}
```

This could fix your issue

Comment: If i dont add `this` to `currTime()` im reciveing the error not found, and now when i add it, im still getting: `TypeError: this.currTime is not a function`